# Regex for lex file to match printf and scanf statements

Tags: c, regex, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am trying to make a compiler where the lex file matches the following simple variants of printf and scanf statements:

```
printf("\n Enter your string:");
scanf("%s",str);
scanf("%d",&prelength);
```

In the scanf examples `str` is declared as `char str[20]` and `prelength` as `int prelength`.

The regex that I currently include in my lex file is the following (for scanf and printf respectively):

```
scanf\(\"([\w\W]*(%[d|c|f|lf|s])*)+\"(,\s*&?[a-zA-Z]+)*\); 
printf\(\"([\w\W]*(%[d|c|f|lf|s])*)+\"(,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*\);
```

I don't know why the above regular expressions aren't matching with the above given examples of printf and scanf (similar to those found in c, but simpler).

Comment: What's your goal? Creating tokens for a parser to consume? Finding all calls of `scanf` and `printf` without a parser? Something else? In either case, are you sure that matching the entire function call in a single regex is the best way to accomplish your goals?

Comment: @sepp2k , well part of the goal is to create tokens for the parser to consume, yes. The final goal is to check if the type indicated by the format specifier matches the actual type of the variable being passed (by looking up a symbol table that I've already implemented). Maybe I'm speaking from a point of ignorance, but I do think that matching the entire function should satisfy my requirements.

Comment: You should really not write your parsers like this. Tokenize using much simpler tokens, such as "scanf" and "printf", pass brackets as separate tokens, pass strings as separate tokens.

Comment: @adi If you match the whole call as one token, then the tokenization for the input in your question would consist of only three tokens: one for the printf and two for the scanf. All the parser could do with that would be to put those three tokens into a list. Then you'd have a syntax tree consisting of only three tokens with no nested structure. In order to do any sort of analysis on that, you'd have to access the text of the tokens, take it apart and determine its structure because clearly just that sequence of token isn't nearly enough information. ...

Comment: ...  In other words you'd have to add another pass of tokenization and parsing after you supposedly already performed those steps. So the original tokenization and parsing steps would basically be for nothing. What you really want is a sequence of tokens that can be parsed into a tree where you can access the individual arguments of the called functions at the very least.

Comment: Thanks for all this super useful info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two `scanf` lines are actually matched successfully. The `printf` line isn't matched because the pattern for the string literal does not match. The problem is that lex does not understand `\w` or `\W`, so `[\w\W]` only matches the letters `w` and `W`.

If lex did support `\w` and `\W`, then `[\w\W]` would match every character that is or isn't a "word character". In other words it would match everything. So this tells us that instead of `[\w\W]`, you can just write `.`, which is supported by lex and does match everything. It also tells us that the `(%[d|c|f|lf|s])*)+` bit is redundant because everything that could be matched by that part would already have been matched by the `.*` part. Consequently the `+` qualifier on the outside is also redundant.

So with that in mind the regex for string literals would become `\".*\"` (which doesn't match newlines, but that's okay because C doesn't allow unescaped newlines in string literals). The problem with that is that this will match everything from the first `"` in the input to the *last* `"`, not the *next* `"`. So you want to prohibit `"`s from appearing within the string. However, a `"` inside a string is allowed when it is escaped by preceding it with a backslash (and so are newlines). So taking all that into account, a suitable regex for string literals is:

```
\"(\\(.|\n)|[^\n\\"])*\"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! And yes, I will need to change the fundamental structure of my lexer and parser as well. Thanks for this additional insight!